# Option for DOCKER_BUILDKIT in PyCharm Docker Interpreter

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, interpreter

Where can I enable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` option in PyCharm for Docker interpreter?

I tried the following and it returns a buildkit related error<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMpOJ.png)</sup>, already set configuration in Docker Desktop <sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmK3s.png)</sup>

[image: PyCharm settings dialog]

[image: Docker configuration]

```
Connecting to Docker daemon�Connected
Waiting for build operation�
Step 1/8 : FROM base/image:master
 ---> daee1e3e0fcb
 ...

Step 7/8 : RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install -r requirements.txt &&     chmod +x run.sh
Error response from daemon: the --mount option requires BuildKit. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build images with BuildKit enabled
Build completed

Unable to find an image for introspection
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same problem, and an alternate I have found is to just build the Dockerfile using an image tag like `project-python:latest-dev` and use this image tag with the `Pull` option rather than the `Build` option (on the above page in your screenshot).

Comment: Same with my current workaround, it feels not right for me

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

<s>I think I just figured this out.</s> I did not figure this out...
My proposed solution is for the Run/Debug configuration as used by `docker-compose` and not `docker build`.

---

### Original Answer

After you create the Docker server, create a Run/Debug configuration in your project. After you choose the Docker server, you specify the Compose files in the Run section. Click the Modify Options button and add it as an Environment variable.

[image: A picture from my Mac]

Hope this works for you!

Comment: this is for the run/debug config not interpreter